# Regexp in a variable Shell

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I'm doing some regexp in shell to find coding style error in *.c files.
Actually I'm doing something like this:

```
# Operator <
if [[ "$1" =~ ([^ ]<|<[^ =$]) ]]; then
    warn "$wmsg_space_operator (operator: <)"
fi
```

But I want to do it like this:

```
# Operator <
regexpOp=([^ ]<|<[^ =$])
if [[ "$1" =~ $regexpOp ]]; then
    warn "$wmsg_space_operator (operator: <)"
fi
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `regexpOp` in quotes

```
regexpOp='([^ ]<|<[^ =$])'
```

and rest is assured

**Why?**

Your regex string contain spaces and anything after the space will be counted as another command.

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote the assignment, specifically for the whitespace.

```
# Operator <
regexpOp="([^ ]<|<[^ =$])"
if [[ "$1" =~ $regexpOp ]]; then
    warn "$wmsg_space_operator (operator: <)"
fi
```